# change properties for a movie clip without instance name (only a string with the name of the class)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movieclip with class "myClass" and no instance name. I'm trying to change the alpha using this

```
var i:int = this.numChildren;
while(i--){
    if (this.getChildAt(i) is myClass){

        this.getChildAt(i).alpha = 0.5;
    }
}
```

I have two problems with this approach:

1- I can't use the string name of the class. There is no getClass or some method to compare like?

```
if (this.getChildAt(i) is "myClass"){
```

2- When I find the movieclip and change the alpha, I break the existing animation. why?

Thanks

Comment: Please create two separate issues. For this I will answer the class name stuff. FYI changing `alpha` of objects that are involved in timeline animations does not work (it does break the animation, so try to target something which is a level lower. `myObject.stuffToUpdate.alpha = 0.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getDefinitionByName()` [(see docs here)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29) is what you need.

```
var className:String = "com.MyClass";
var clazz:Class = flash.utils.getDefinitionByName(className) as Class;
var i:int = this.numChildren;

while(i--){
    if (this.getChildAt(i) is clazz){
        this.getChildAt(i).alpha = 0.5;
    }
}
```